# Can someone walk me through the Java recursion process for this code?

Tags: java, recursion

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the process of recursion for this specific code.

```
public static void testMethod(int n){

      if(n > 0){
         testMethod(n-1);
         System.out.print("A");
         testMethod(n-1);
         System.out.print("B");
      }
}
```

For example, if in my main method I type

```
testMethod(2);
```

The output for the code is: `ABAABB`.

In my head I am thinking this code would run until `n=0` making it skip the `if` statement, but run a total of 3 times and output `AB` each time. Clearly, I am not thinking of this correctly.

If anyone could walk me through the process of why this is `ABAABB` and not something like `ABABAB` I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Try printing out the current value of `n` with the letter (and maybe use `println` instead for neatness sake). That will likely cause this to make much more sense. With how you're looking at it now, you can't see how "deep" into the recursion you are, which makes the output not near as useful.

Comment: Put the print with `n` before the `if` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to remenber that, once a recursion is called, all the instructions in that sub call are executed before the remaining instructions in the parent get executed. And there're two recursion calls to (n-1) in your code, one before each print.

Let's try to visualize the call stack for testMethod(2) :
n=2 > 0, then main stack is :

```
1. testMethod(1); // 2- 1
2. System.out.print("A");
3. testMethod(1); // 2 - 1
4. System.out.print("B");`
```

Now let's consider the subcall testMethod(1)
n=1 > 0, stack for testMethod(1); =>

```
testMethod(0); // 1-1
System.out.print("A");
testMethod(0); // 1 -1
System.out.print("B");`
```

Since testMethod(0); doesn't do anything ( 0 is not > 0) we can remove testMethod(0) to simplify the stack for testMethod(1); =>

```
System.out.print("A");
System.out.print("B");`
```

Now let's replace that back in the main stack for testMethod(2) =>

```
1.1 System.out.print("A");//-----
                                 //-----> testMethod(1)
1.2 System.out.print("B");`//----

2. System.out.print("A");

3.1 System.out.print("A");//-----
                                 //-----> second testMethod(1)
3.2 System.out.print("B");`//----

4. System.out.print("B");`
```

Which then prints out in order ABAABB

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can actually step through this visualizing what **n** will be each step along the way.

Probably the most important point is that when the recursion gets to 1-case, it prints "**AB**," but even when it is not in its 1-case, it will print an **A** after calling itself the first time and **B** after calling itself the second time.  So when we call for 2, we expect a 1-case ("**AB**"), then an "**A**" and then a 1-case ("**AB**"), and then a "**B**".  Or "**ABAABB**"

```
testMethod(2) {
--testMethod(1) {
----testMethod(0);
----System.out.print("A");
----testMethod(0);
----System.out.print("B");
--}
--System.out.print("A");
--testMethod(1) {
----testMethod(0);
----System.out.print("A");
----testMethod(0);
----System.out.print("B");
--}
-- System.out.print("B");
}
```

If you walk through the prints in order, it makes sense that you would get this output.

Answer (score 1):

So first **testMethod** ist called with **2**.
Its checking if 2 > 0 -> true

Now lets say to make it more clear **testMethod1** is called with **1**
Its checking if 1 > 0 -> true

Now **testMethod2** is called with **0**.

0 > 0 -> false
this call does nothing so back to *testMethod1*

**testMethod1** prints A
calls **testMethod3** with **0** so nothing happens again and back to *testMethod1* again
**testMethod1** print B
and now we're going back to the original *testMethod* call

A is printed
and now we're doing the same stuff again so AB is printed and finally B

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of illustration, let's pretend that `testMethod(n-1)` prints "-". Then `testMethod(n)` will print out "-A-B".

Answer (score 1):

So let's say your code lines are

```
public static void testMethod(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        testMethod(n - 1);       /* line1 */
        System.out.print("A");   /* line2 */
        testMethod(n - 1);       /* line3 */
        System.out.print("B");   /* line4 */
    }                            /* line5 */
}
```

Then you'd have these steps:

```
 1. n=2: line1 -> testMethod(n=1)
 2. n=1: line1 -> testMethod(n=0)
 3. n=0: line5 -> return
 4. n=1: line2 -> prints "A"
 5. n=1: line3 -> testMethod(n=0) 
 6. n=0: line5 -> return
 7. n=1: line4 -> prints "B"
 8. n=1: line5 -> return
 9. n=2: line2 -> prints "A"
10. n=2: line3 -> testMethod(n=1)
11. n=1: see 2-8
... n=1:          prints "AB"
18. n=2: line4 -> prints "B"
19. n=2: line5 -> return
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with tree structure and its traversal then it is much easier to understand the working process of any recursion method.
For this method the recursion tree will be something like this:

[image]

For n=2, the complete tree will be the following:

[image]

Now you need to traverse the tree fro left to right (inorder-based, only leaves), you will get:

print ("A")  print ("B")  print ("A")  print ("A")  print ("B")  print ("B")

which is : ABAABB

Answer (score 0):

in Java we have a stack that stores all our calls with the values

in your first call your program will hold a stack reference to your first call with value 2 so we can say

```
public static void testMethod(2){

      if(2 > 0){
Label A: testMethod(1); ==> this will trigger a call and our stack will refer to this line to coninue when the method ends
         System.out.print("A");
         testMethod(1);
         System.out.print("B");
      }
}
```

our Label A will look like the following and you have to know that we have no printing till now

```
public static void testMethod(1){

      if(1 > 0){
Label B: testMethod(0); ==> in this case we have a new method call, new stack reference and we wait for this method return so we continue to next line
         System.out.print("A");
         testMethod(0);
         System.out.print("B");
      }
}
```

if we try to look at the stack with our eyes we will see that

testMethod(2) wait in Label A ==> call TestMethod(1) wait in Label B call testMehod(0)

you know that 0 is not greater than 0 so you will terminate without processing

this will free the label B to jump to next line where it will print A then call with 0 value wich will do nothing then print B

here is our first AB

now it will return to label A and jump to next line and print A

we have ABA
we will recall another time the testMethod1 we know that this road has printed AB so we will have

ABA+AB = ABAAB then the call terminate and finish by priting B and exit the call of testMethod(2)

with printing ABAABB